# Manifest.json not being downloaded?

Tags: html, google-chrome, manifest

I'm following [Google's progressive web-app recommendations](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android).  I have a webpage that links to a manifest file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>my site</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look like the manifest is being downloaded.  When I view the network tab in Chrome, I see no evidence that it's been downloaded, and the Manifest tab shows nothing.

I have confirmed `manifest.json` is accessible, when I hit `https://example.com/manifest.json` it comes up.

I've tried various paths including "/manifest.json".

Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache "This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped."

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm refering to https://w3c.github.io/manifest

Comment: You're using Chrome? Check the "Browser compatibility" table at the bottom of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest, then. Just "basic support" in Firefox right now, looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my manifest.json was invalid.

[image: Invalid]